# regex to match string with numbers

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a query string stored in a variable and I need to strip out some stuff from it using preg_replace()

the parameters I want to strip out look like this:

```
&filtered_features[48][]=491
```

As there will be multiples of these parameters in the query string the 48 and the 491 can be any number so the regex needs to essentially match this:

```
'&filtered_features[' + Any number + '][]=' + Any number
```

Anyone know how I would do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string = '&filtered_features[48][]=491';

$string = preg_replace('/\[\d+\]\[\]=\d+/', '[][]=', $string);

echo $string;
```

I assume you wanted to remove the numbers from the string. This will match a multi-variable query string as well since it just looks for [A_NUMBER][]=A_NUMBER and changes it to [][]=

Answer (score 0):

```
$query_string = "&filtered_features[48][]=491&filtered_features[49][]=492";
$lines = explode("&", $query_string);
$pattern = "/filtered_features\[([0-9]*)\]\[\]=([0-9]*)/";
foreach($lines as $line)
{
    preg_match($pattern, $line, $m);
    var_dump($m);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/\&filtered_features\[(?<n1>\d*)\]\[\]\=(?<n2>\d*)/'
```

this will match first number in n1 and second in n2

```
preg_match_all( '/\&filtered_features\[(?<n1>\d*)\]\[\]\=(?<n2>\d*)/', $str, $matches);
```

cryptic answer will replace more than necessary with this string:

```
&something[1][]=123&filtered_features[48][]=491
```